# Update MongoDB from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a row in MongoDB using mongoose I pass account number which is unique but I can't get this row updated.

```
this.update({account_no:key},{valid:'true'},{ upsert: true }, function(){});
```

What is wrong with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try

```
this.update({account_no:key}, { $set: { valid: 'true' }},{ upsert: true }, function(){});
```

and make use of the **$set** in update parameter.
Could be the it!

Comment: Damn. What if you query the collection by account_no first, and in callback set the valid attribute of the resulting object to true and call .save() on the object for updating, as a workaround?

Comment: I tried this code this.findOne({ account_no: key }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return callback(err); }
      if (!user) { return callback(null, false); }
     user.valid='false';
     user.save();
    }); but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Okay, that's exactly the way I would to it. I think you need to utilize the console.log(); function to debug some values. save() has a callback to and you could check for errors like .save(function(err) { console.log(err); }); And I would recommend to log the "err" and "user" vars from findOne to console, too.

Comment: Thanks tomasz. The problem is that valid was of type boolean and I was supplying string. When I change it to boolean it works.

Comment: For a second I thought: "Should I ask him, if valid is really a string, neeaah". Anyway, have a nice weekend.